# Calcular a média de valores onde campos são iguais

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Possuo uma tabela, em banco *mysql*, que recebe alguns dados referente a avaliações. Como posso calcular a média destas avaliações diretamente na *query*, com base na pergunta?
Tentei de várias maneiras, inclusive pesquisando aqui, e não consegui.

```
SELECT perg.pergunta, resp.resposta, (SELECT AVG(resposta) FROM resp_pergunta_man) as media FROM resp_pergunta_man AS resp 
LEFT JOIN pergunta_man AS perg ON (perg.codigo = resp.pergunta)
```

Resultado obtido:

```
pergunta                     |   resposta    |   media
_____________________________|_______________|______________________   
Tempo de resposta do chamado |    4          |    5.666666666666667
Cumprimento do prazo         |    9          |    5.666666666666667
Qualidade da solução         |    4          |    5.666666666666667
Conhecimento do Técnico      |    6          |    5.666666666666667
Canal telefônico             |    5          |    5.666666666666667
Portal Hórus Manutenção      |    4          |    5.666666666666667
Tempo de resposta do chamado |    3          |    5.666666666666667
Cumprimento do prazo         |    8          |    5.666666666666667
Qualidade da solução         |    6          |    5.666666666666667
Conhecimento do Técnico      |    2          |    5.666666666666667
Canal telefônico             |    8          |    5.666666666666667
Portal Hórus Manutenção      |    9          |    5.666666666666667
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrupando através do `GROUP BY`, veja um exemplo:

```
SELECT perg.pergunta, AVG(resp.resposta) as media 
FROM resp_pergunta_man AS resp 
LEFT JOIN pergunta_man AS perg ON (perg.codigo = resp.pergunta) 
group by perg.pergunta
```